# Setting defaults with keyval-interface - do it in the current scope or do it globally?

Tags: macros, best-practices, key-value

Assume a LaTeX 2e-macro, be it named `\foo`, which processes the content of one optional argument via keyval-syntax.

E.g., `\foo[key1=value1, key2=value2,...,\keyN=valueN]`

I would also like to have a macro
`\setfoodefaults{key1=value1, key2=value2,...,\keyN=valueN}`

so that after
`\setfoodefaults{key1=foo, key2=bar,...,\keyN=baz}`
the call
`\foo %`
will yield the same as the call
`\foo[key1=foo, key2=bar,...,\keyN=baz]%`.

In other words: Via `\setfoodefaults` you can set default values for each key. Such a default value shall be applied when the key in question is not specified at all in the key-value-list of `\foo`'s optional argument.

(Be aware that not specifying a key at all within a key-value-list is different from specifying a key without a value: In the latter case the default value specified by means of the corresonding `\define@key`-command gets used. I am after specifying (other) default values that are to be used in the further case.)

The question is:

Which practice is better:

Should a macro `\setfoodefaults` change/set the default values only within the current scope/group?

Should a macro `\setfoodefaults` change/set the default values globally?

Comment: everything is local in latex unless explicitly documented as global so local is the natural choice unless you are setting things that are inherently global such as properties of the whole document

Comment: You could add a `global`-key to `\setfoodefaults` so the user can choose whether changes of defaults are global or restricted to the current/local scope. By the way: Probably a macro `\setfoodefaults` is not needed at all. You could add a key to `\foo` so that the values specified will henceforth also be defaults globally or within the current scope.

Comment: As a user I would probably expect the default settings to be global (otherwise what is the point of setting defaults if you have to do it again in a new scope), similar to using commands like `\lstset` (listings), `\setminted` (minted) or `\setkeys{Gin}` (graphicx).

Comment: @Marijn I think you're confusing things. All the examples you give will work on the current group and every subgroup, so are local. The thing is that you use such settings commands usually at the top level which then acts on the entire document. Indeed applying on a local scale is usually what you want and is way more handy. `pgfkeys` doesn't even support globally acting keys out of the box for example.